# Glide version 4.7.1 can't load Gif to ImageView when I add RequestListener

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

When I tried to load from a gif url to a ImageView, I added more condition by RequestListener, but It didn't work|

**Glide version**: 4.7.1
it worked when I coded: 
`Glide.with(context).asGif().load(gifModel.url).into(ivGif);`

I want  after loading gif completely, ivPreGif  GONE

I added more contition but I didn't work

```
Glide.with(context)
                                .asGif()
                                .load(gifModel.url)
                                .listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        ivPreGif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        ivGif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                })
                                .into(ivGif);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

load method give your gif url.

```
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.user).into(imageView);

  Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.user)
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                     ivPreGif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I want to after loading gif completely, ivPreGif  GONE

Comment: thank you, but It only works to loading Image, doesn't work to loading GIF
Do u know how to load GIF with GifDrawable?

Comment: make sure that you remove ".asGif()"